# I have a frozen fish head. What should I do with it?

Tags: fish, soup, stock

I butterflied a whole dorade but removed the head. It's now sitting in the freezer waiting for a soup or stock. Does anyone know a more interesting or creative use for fish heads?

Comment: I've heard that if you take them to the movies you get in for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

South-east Asian cuisine often uses fish heads in stews or steamed. I remember seeing a recipe for fish head stew. Try this one: http://www.malaysianfood.net/recipes/recipefishheadcurry.htm

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could look into making your own fermented fish sauce, but for that you are really supposed to use whole small fish. And a single head will not get you very far.

If you had heads from larger fish you could cut out the cheeks and cook something with those. I had a pasta dish once where the sauce was made with cod cheeks and that was delicious. Having said that though, it is still just fish meat. The cheek meat is not *that* different from cod fillet.

As for your single dorade head, your best bet is probably still to use it for stock or soup. I usually keep two boxes in the freezer, one for meat and one for fish, where I just toss anything that will work in a stock. Fish heads, prawn shells, chicken carcasses, meat trimmings, it all goes in there. Even vegetables, like carrots that have gone soft, leek greens etc. Once the boxes are filled up I make the stock and start the box over again.

Comment: I do the same with my scraps as well. It's great! Thanks for the comment.